# Is opening for append safe?

Tags: python, linux, file, corruption

If a file is opened with write permissions, there's a chance of corruption in case of crashes/bugs/etc. Therefore i believe it is a good idea to make backup in those cases and set up the program so that only one of those files is being edited at same time, so that in case of corruption only one of the files gets corrupted. What if a file is opened for append (but not for write), is it still recommended to make backups, or no longer necessary?

In case it matters, i am using python and linux currently.

Comment: i'm in favor of backup

Comment: file being open in append is just file being open for write, but the seek pointer is at the end instead of the start.

Comment: @thethiny, not quite right. The OS also guarantees that new writes will go to the end _even if another program is appending at the same time_ when `O_APPEND` is used; whereas without `O_APPEND`, you can have two different programs having different ideas of where "the end" is, such that one program's writes overwrite the other's.

Comment: @AnswerMyQuestion, ...I'm not convinced that this question is answerable. "Is X safe?" depends on which kinds of failures you decide are common enough to be worth protecting against, and which kinds of failures you decide _aren't_. We don't know your failure model, and without one there isn't really any basis to decide what's considered "good enough" for any specific use case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I mean to at least ask whether "open for append" is safer than "open for write", which afaik might have some answer.

Comment: @AnswerMyQuestion, ...categorically, yes, it's safer (which is to say: there are fewer possible failure modes in play). "No longer necessary to make backups" is a very different thing.

Comment: BTW, note that the guarantees that writes to a file opened with `O_APPEND` are atomic are only true to the extent that those writes are small enough to fit inside a single invocation of the `write()` syscall (if large writes are split up, they can be interleaved with writes by other processes at the boundary), and also that some popular filesystems (_ahem_ NFS _ahem_) don't promise to honor the POSIX standard's guarantees on the subject. Above caveats being part of why I'd be very hesitant to categorically say that something is "safe" without knowing the use case / deployment environment / etc

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Linux breaks that guarantee for all filesystems, apparently. See https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55651 Gotta love the lame passive-voiced "the write is interrupted" as the explanation. as if there's no control over that. And FWIW [`pwrite()` does allow writing to an arbitrary location in a file even if `O_APPEND` is set](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html): "The pwrite() function shall be equivalent to write(), except that it writes into a given position and does not change the file offset (regardless of whether O_APPEND is set)."

Comment: (cont), Of course, that's [broken on Linux, too](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html#BUGS): "POSIX requires that opening a file with the `O_APPEND` flag should
       have no effect on the location at which `pwrite()` writes data.
       However, on Linux, if a file is opened with `O_APPEND`, `pwrite()`
       appends data to the end of the file, regardless of the value of
       `offset`."